# Out of memory on a 11223056-byte allocation

Tags: android, image, memory

I searched about this problem, and I read that most of the time is related to the use `Bitmap`.

But in my case i don't use `Bitmap`,

I have a `GridView`, which on click on an item goes to the detail page. In the detail page, i set a background image random in this way:

```
int[] imageList = new int[]{R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
                            R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine};

...

@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  Random ran = new Random();
  int imageInt = ran.nextInt(8)+1;

  image.setImageResource(imageList[imageInt]);

}
```

**the problem appears each about 4 times when I go into the detail page, not always, but approximately every 4 times**

the screen comes black for some seconds and after i have this error:

```
Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

but the app does not crash, only the black screen for a few seconds and then returns the app...

**all images are the same size, and are about 15kb**

thanks everybody

Comment: you use images. to be drawn, they are always uncompressed as bitmap first. meaning their size is not the small gif size, it is width*height*4.

Comment: @njzk2 oh, i don't know.. can i solve this problem?

Comment: i don't understand your question. start by looking at the actual size of the images. (every images, not only these. It can be any background ...). Also, post your stacktrace.

Comment: @njzk2 What is not clear to you? Tell me and I'll try to explain better

Comment: Start by this : post your stacktrace. Any time you ask a question about a crash, post your stacktrace.

Comment: @njzk2 i'm trying to print stack trace, but adding this line: Log.d("myapp ", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception())); every time print the same things .. What am I doing wrong? thanks for your time

Comment: this line `Out of memory on a 11223056-byte allocation` usually comes with a red stacktrace. tracing a `new Exception` does not really do anything.

Comment: @njzk2 that line compare alone, and after few seconds compare: E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust your manifest file. Add android:largeHeap="true" to the application tag.

Comment: Can you explain why this should fix?

Comment: thanks, this seems to work, but i don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

If it is every one in 4 starts it sounds like one or two of your random images are giving you trouble. I would recommend to lgo which image is tried to set and if you find out a specific image is the culprit try to find out what is the matter with that file. Maybe you forgot to scale down one of the graphics?

Comment: thanks for your response, all images are the same size, and are about 15kb, but i'll try to see if is the same image that create this issue

Comment: I tried now to see if it was some image in particular to give problems, but not does not depend from the images

Comment: 15Kb is irrelevant as it is the compressed size. You need to look at the in memory size.